# Photoshop : How to convert Text to outline vector?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, text

In photoshop : How do I convert a a type layer into a vector outline (Just like in Illustrator)?

For the final purpose of copying this and pasting into Adobe Animate CC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highlight the type layer in the **Layers Panel**

Choose `Type > Convert to Shape` from the menu

https://helpx.adobe.com/support/photoshop.html

You're aware you can move *live* type from Photoshop to Illustrator often by merely *opening* the .psd with Illustrator and choosing appropriate options.